# Работа с canvas через функцию

Tags: delphi, ооп, delphi-7, функции

Как можно работать с canvas через функцию? Внизу один и тот же код, но через обработчик событий работает, а через функцию выдаёт ошибку.Что нужно исправить?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image1.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clBlack;
  Image1.Canvas.Rectangle(1,1,50,50);
end;

function f():byte;
begin
  Image1.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clBlack;
  Image1.Canvas.Rectangle(1,1,50,50);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   f;
end;
```

Ошибка:

> Undeclared identifier: 'Image1'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Данная ошибка возникает из-за того, что `Image1` это не глобальный объект, а поле класса `TForm1`. Обработчик - метод этого класса и видит это поле, а для сторонней функции оно недоступно.

Можно сделать так

```
function f():byte;
begin
  Form1.Image1.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clBlack;
  Form1.Image1.Canvas.Rectangle(1, 1, 50, 50);
end;
```

Но это **ОЧЕНЬ** неправильно. Т.к. идет ненужное обращение к глобальной переменной.

Можно в функцию передать указатель на объект класса `TForm1`

```
function f(AForm: TForm1):byte;
begin
  AForm.Image1.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clBlack;
  AForm.Image1.Canvas.Rectangle(1, 1, 50, 50);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   f(Self);
end;
```

но это глупо. С тем же успехом можно сделать `f` методом класса `TForm`. Вы же, как я понимаю, хотите написать функцию для рисования прямоугольника на произвольной канве. Тогда все, что нужно, это передать в функцию указатель на нужную канву

```
procedure f(ACanvas: TCanvas)
begin
  ACanvas.Brush.Color:=clBlack;
  ACanvas.Rectangle(1, 1, 50, 50);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   f(Image1.Canvas);
end;
```

Начиная с Delphi 2006 можно написать хелпер для класса `TCanvas` и сделать `f` псевдометодом этого класса

```
type
  TCanvasHelper = class helper for TCanvas
  public
    procedure f;
  end;

procedure TCanvasHelper.f
begin
  Brush.Color:=clBlack;
  Rectangle(1, 1, 50, 50);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Image1.Canvas.f;
end;
```